# Can I run a DHCP server on an ubuntu VM under vmware and serve the host?

Tags: networking

I have Windows 7. I installed Vmware Workstation and then installed Ubuntu on it.

Now I want to have a DHCP server on Ubuntu and DHCP client on Windows 7. What should I do? How should I configure ubuntu, vmware, and windows 7? Please explain it clearly in detail and from very beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will not be as clear as you would like it, but in short this is it:

1. The VM must have a bridged network card, so that it can contact the outside world. In VMWare you can set this before you start the machine.
2. (I usually set the servers network card to a fixed address).
3. Follow the documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/dhcp.html) to set up the dhcp server. Or you can use dnsmasq, which is a bit easier.
4. Windows 7 will automatically get the address, if everything is ok with ubuntu.

But may I ask that why do you want a configuration like this?

Comment: It's a university assignment. How can give IP to ubuntu? I want DHCP server for ubuntu and the client one for windows 7. please elaborate the issue because I'm a beginner.

Comment: The dhcp server must have a fixed ip address. The howto can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Comment: You need to edit /etc/network/interfaces file, and add the static settings there.

Answer (score 2):

1. start your VM with network setting Bridge Network Card
2. start ubuntu server and install the DHCP server

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server or isc-dhcp-server
   ```
3. Configure it:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
   ```

   add the following lines

   ```
   subnet 192.168.1.0 
   netmask 255.255.255.0

   { range 192.168.1.150 192.168.1.200; 
   option routers 192.168.1.254;
   option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;
   default-lease-time 600; max-lease-time 7200;
   }
   ```

   Then run

   ```
   sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
   ```

   you are done

In case you are getting errors that it cannot start, proceed with the following steps:

1. restart your Ethernet card

   ```
   sudo ifdown ethx
   ```

   it shut down your Ethernet, x means 0,1,2... use `ifconfig` for this
2. now restart your Ethernet

   ```
   sudo ifup ethx
   ```
3. restart your network manager

   ```
   sudo service network-manager stop

   sudo service network-manager start

   sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
   ```

   (`restart` may give you error because your dhcp server is not already running you can try `start`)
4. one reason behind this is IPV6 so disable it

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
   ```

   add the following lines to file

   ```
   # # IPv6    
   net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
   ```
5. Enter following command to restart `sysctl` settings:

   ```
   sudo sysctl -p
   ```

#### Important note

Disable DHCP of your router because ubuntu use DHCP of your router by default
or some router having DHCP enable has ability to disable the DHCP server machine. I don't know why.

if you want to give static ip to your linux machine then do the following but it depends

Edit the `interfaces` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

add the following lines for example

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Please use proper formatting. I [reverted](http://askubuntu.com/posts/318076/revisions) your edit which basically reverted all formatting I added earlier.